# copy range of cells from current worksheet and paste it to a text file. The text file should always get updated with the new versions

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to copy and paste a range of cell values from my current worksheet into a text document. In the VBA code below, I'm able to copy the cell values to the txt file, but I'm facing issues with the naming of the text file.

My desired output are the following 6 points:

1. When the code is run, it should copy a range of cells from my current worksheet
2. Create a text file with name "Unsuppression_*dd.MM*_01", where dd.MM is the current date and month, and 01 is the version number.
3. Paste the cell value to the text file and close it.
4. Then, when the code is run for 2nd time, it should copy the cell values and then create a text file with incremented version ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_02") and paste it in that. It should also delete the previous version text file ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_01")
5. Then, when the code is run for 3rd time, it should copy the cell values and then create a text file with incremented version ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_03") and paste it in that. It should also delete the previous version text file ("Unsuppression_dd.MM_02"). This should keep happening.
6. The last thing in my desire output is that, when the date is changed, i.e., when I run the code on a new day, I want Version 01 with the new day's date to appear and all of the text files from the prior day to be removed.

When I run the code below, it creates txt file with Version "01". The 2nd time I run the code it deletes the previous version and creates Version "02", but after this when I run the code for a 3rd time, it cycles back to version "01" before it begins to increase. Instead of cycling back to the version "01", I want it to keep incrementing. I'm not able to solve this problem.

```
Sub UpdateTextFileWithVersion() 
' Define folder path 
Dim folderPath As String 
folderPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\SIM_macro\Unsuppression_" & Format(Date, "dd.MM") & "_"
' Define range to copy
Dim copyRange As Range
Set copyRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H2:H8")

' Copy values to array
Dim valuesArray As Variant
valuesArray = copyRange.Value

' Determine the next version number
Dim versionNumber As Integer
versionNumber = 1

' Check for existing versions and delete them
Do While Dir(folderPath & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".txt") <> ""
    ' Delete the previous version with a delay
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' 1 second delay
    Kill folderPath & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".txt"
    
    ' Increment version number
    versionNumber = versionNumber + 1
Loop

' Open file for writing with the correct version number
Dim fileNumber As Integer
fileNumber = FreeFile
Open folderPath & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".txt" For Output As fileNumber

' Write values to file
For i = 1 To UBound(valuesArray, 1)
    Print #fileNumber, valuesArray(i, 1)
Next i

' Close file
Close fileNumber
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When you run the code for the 3rd time, `Dir()` is goint to check `*_01.txt`. There isn't version 1 text file in the folder. `Do` loop is skipped. Then the code will create `*_01.txt`.

```
versionNumber = 1
Do While Dir(folderPath & Format(versionNumber, "00") & ".txt") <> ""
```

---

- Assumes there is not multiple version text files in the folder

```vb
    ' Determine the next version number
    Dim versionNumber As Integer, aTxt
    Dim fName As String, baseFolder As String
    baseFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\SIM_macro\"
    versionNumber = 1
    
    ' Check for existing versions and delete them
    fName = Dir(folderPath & "*.txt")
    If Len(fName) > 0 Then
        ' Delete the previous version with a delay
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' 1 second delay
        Kill baseFolder & fName
        aTxt = Split(fName, "_")
        ' Increment version number
        versionNumber = CInt(Left(aTxt(UBound(aTxt)), 2)) + 1
    End If
```

---

***Update:***

```vb
    ' Determine the next version number
    Dim versionNumber As Integer, aTxt
    Dim sSearchName As String, sBaseFolder As String
    Dim sTxtName As String, iVer As Long
    sBaseFolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\SIM_macro\"
    sTxtName = "Unsuppression_" & Format(Date, "dd.MM") & "_"
    folderPath = sBaseFolder + sTxtName
    versionNumber = 1
    
    ' Check for existing versions and delete them
    sSearchName = Dir(sBaseFolder & "*.txt")
    Do While sSearchName <> vbNullString
        ' Extract ver # from Today's txt file
        If UCase(sSearchName) Like UCase(sTxtName & "??.txt") Then
            aTxt = Split(sSearchName, "_")
            ' Increment version number
            iVer = CInt(Left(aTxt(UBound(aTxt)), 2)) + 1
            If iVer > versionNumber Then versionNumber = iVer
        End If
        ' Delete the previous version with a delay
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' 1 second delay
        Kill sBaseFolder & sSearchName
        sSearchName = Dir()
    Loop
```

Comment: Hi @taller, i added the above answer to my vba, and the deleting of previous versions & creating new text file with incremented version - is working great. I just have one issue - when i change my date to 21st Nov(in my windows system setting), after i run the code, it creates a new txt file "Unsuppression_21.11_01), but it retains the previous day's last created txt file version (Considering i used it 5 times today - the last created text file in my folder path is "Unsuppression_20.05"). I'm not sure if its issue in the way i added your answer to my code, or am I missing something in my vba.

Comment: I think you missed this part of requirement in your post. I have updated the code.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't clearly mention all the requirements of the VBA code earlier in my post. I have updated it. I sincerely appreciate your response. The  final update that you provided functions flawlessly and does every task specified and produces the desired outcome for me. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

### Export Range to New Version of Text File

```vb
Sub ExportRangeToTextFile()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Range to Text File"
    Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Desktop\SIM_macro\" ' ???
    'Dim FOLDER_PATH As String:
    'FOLDER_PATH = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\SIM_macro\"
    Const FILE_NAME_BASE As String = "Unsuppression_"
    Const DATE_FORMAT As String = "dd.mm"
    Const VERSION_FORMAT As String = "00"
    Const DATE_VERSION_DELIMITER As String = "_"
    Const FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".txt"
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const COPY_RANGE As String = "H2:H8"
    Const DELETE_OLD_VERSIONS As Boolean = True
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(COPY_RANGE)
    Dim Data() As Variant: Data = rg.Value
    
    Dim fNameLeft As String: fNameLeft = FILE_NAME_BASE _
        & Format(Date, DATE_FORMAT) & DATE_VERSION_DELIMITER
        
    Dim vPattern As String: vPattern = String(Len(VERSION_FORMAT), "?")
    
    Dim DirPattern As String: DirPattern = FOLDER_PATH & fNameLeft _
        & vPattern & FILE_EXTENSION
    
    Dim fName As String: fName = Dir(DirPattern)
    Dim vNew As Long: vNew = 1
    
    If Len(fName) > 0 Then
        
        Dim vStart As Long: vStart = Len(fNameLeft) + 1
        Dim vLen As Long: vLen = Len(VERSION_FORMAT)
        
        Dim vOld As Long, vOldString As String
        
        Do While Len(fName) > 0
            vOldString = Mid(fName, vStart, vLen)
            If IsNumeric(vOldString) Then
                vOld = CLng(vOldString)
                If vOld >= vNew Then vNew = vOld + 1
                If DELETE_OLD_VERSIONS Then
                    'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01") ' ???
                    Kill FOLDER_PATH & fName
                End If
            End If
            fName = Dir
        Loop
    
    End If
    
    Dim fPath As String: fPath = FOLDER_PATH & fNameLeft _
        & Format(vNew, VERSION_FORMAT) & FILE_EXTENSION
    
    Dim fNumber As Long: fNumber = FreeFile
    
    Open fPath For Output As fNumber
    
        Dim rValue As Variant, r As Long
        
        For r = 1 To UBound(Data, 1)
            rValue = Data(r, 1)
            If IsError(rValue) Then rValue = rg.Cells(r, 1).Text
            Print #fNumber, rValue
        Next r
    
    Close fNumber

    MsgBox "Range """ & rg.Address(0, 0) & """ exported to text file """ _
        & fPath & """.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, this code works very well in incrementing the version code and pasting the values from cell range. Thank you very much. I just have one issue: when I run the code after changing my date in my system settings, the code creates version "01" with the new date and leaves the last created version as it is. Is it possible to delete the prior day's text file version before starting with today's version "01"?

Comment: An example of the issue that I'm facing is: Suppose I execute the code five times today, the last txt file created is "Unsuppression_20.11_05" which is the only text file present in my folderPath. When I run the code after changing the date to November 21st (in my Windows system settings), a new text document named "Unsuppression_21.11_01" is created. After this i ran the code a few more times, and the txt file with the incremented versions were created perfectly fine. But my folder Path would still have the text file "Unsuppression_20.11_05" ( last created version from the previous day).

Comment: My desired output is that - when I run the code on a new day, I want Version 01 with the current date to appear and all of the text files from the prior day to be removed. I've only recently begun studying about VBAs, therefore I have no idea how to change it to achieve the intended outcome. Your help in modifying the answer would be very much appreciated.